# SQL float is slower than Python float

Tags: python, sql, performance, type-conversion

I have some numerical data in stored in SQL DB. I load it to python and do analysis over there. The stored data format is `Decimal`. Since it is a pretty slow format, when I run the script, analysis takes `30 sec`. If I convert the data to `float` in python then conversion take `20 sec` and analysis takes `4 sec` so `24` sec overall. A bit of improvement, but not much, so I tried converting during the SQL query. That almost does not affect the query time, but now the analysis takes `16 sec`. Again, an improvement - but I do not get why the analysis part takes longer now. My guess is that the `float` python converts the data to is faster than `float` that SQL converts into - can that be the case, and are there ways to cope with that?

Please feel free to retag if necessary.

**Edit:** by commenting different parts of the codes, just noticed that in fact it's not about the size of the float. Just my SQL query returns data in the format

> `<SQLrow={a: 1, b: 2}>`

whereas I need

> `(1, 2)`

Can I get the data from SQL directly in the latter format? Currently I use `adodbapi`

Comment: This is database access library specific, so you'll need to tell us which db and access lib you're using.  Additionally, when faced with performance issues, the first tool to use -- always --, is the profiler.

Comment: First of all depends your _actual_ expression. What you wrote on SQL may be pretty different to what you wrote in Python. Anyway...decimal and float are **completely different types**. Decimal has a precision up to 38 digits, SQL float has a precision up to 15 digits...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I've found that the slowing part is in the different place, so it's not really about the floating point.